# splitting models files into multiple separate models give field abstraction error

Tags: django, django-models

My code is as shown below:

**holidayRequest.py**

```
from django.db import models
from enum import Enum

class HolidayRequests(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'holidays_requests'
        app_label = 'dashboard'

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255,null= False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 255,null=False)
    ph_no = models.CharField(max_length =255,null=False)


    holiday = models.ForeignKey('holidays',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**holiday.py**

```
from django.db import models
from enum import Enum

class Holiday (models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'holidays'
        app_label = 'dashboard'

    holiday_price  = models.CharField(max_length = 255,null =False)
    holiday_title = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False)
```

**init.py** (inside models folder)

```
from holidayRequest import HolidayRequests
from holiday import Holiday
```

the moment I run migrations, I get the following error:

```
dashboard.HolidayRequests.holiday: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'holidays', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
dashboard.HolidayRequests.holiday: (fields.E307) The field dashboard.HolidayRequests.holiday was declared with a lazy reference to 'dashboard.holidays', but app 'dashboard' doesn't provide model 'holidays'.
```

Comment: What happen if you remove all `Meta` from models?

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the model name, not the db_table_name

`holiday = models.ForeignKey('Holiday',on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

Also, remove imports from `__init__.py`.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the help. It worked. I have one doubt. For some models foreign key even works with `db_table` name. So how it is working in those cases?